# Does high closure of a forcing poset imply triviality?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

$\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb{P}}$
The general intuition for forcing (at least for me) is that forcing with $\P$ doesn't dramatically affect objects of size $> |\P|$. Of course new large things appear, but these are usually "echoes" of something that happened lower down.

Recall that a poset $\P$ is $\leq\kappa$-closed if any descending chain in $\P$ of length $\leq\kappa$ has a lower bound. A poset $\P$ is $\leq\kappa$-distributive if forcing with $\P$ doesn't add new $\leq\kappa$-sequences of ground model sets. It is easy to see that any $\leq\kappa$-closed poset is $\leq\kappa$-distributive; however, the converse doesn't hold.

There are two closely related questions I want to ask here.

Firstly, suppose we have a forcing poset $\P$ which is $\leq |\P|$-closed (or $\leq |\P|$-distributive). Does this imply that $\P$ is trivial for forcing? If not, is there a bound $\kappa=\kappa(\P)$ such that any $\P$ which is $\leq \kappa(\P)$-closed (or $\leq \kappa(\P)$-distributive) is trivial for forcing?

And secondly, what if, in the above, we replace $|\P|$ with whatever the saturation of $\P$ might be. That is, if $\P$ has $\kappa$-c.c. and is $\leq\kappa$-closed (or distributive), is it trivial for forcing?

Comment: The forcing poset $G$ is a set of size at most $|\mathbb P|$. If no new such sets are added, $\mathbb P$ is trivial.

Comment: (The answer to your second question is also yes, for $\le\kappa$-closure.)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Ah, this is another of my d'oh moments. At the risk of having another, could you elaborate on the $\kappa$-c.c. case? Is it a covering argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that all of the options above imply that $\mathbb{P}$ is trivial.

**Theorem:** If $\mathbb{P}$ is nontrivial and $\leq\kappa$-distributive then $\mathbb{P}$ is not $\kappa$-cc.

To see this first recall that $\mathbb{P}$ being $\leq\kappa$-distributive is equivalent to saying that any collection of $\leq\kappa$ maximal antichains in $\mathbb{P}$ has a common refinement. Using this we can build a tree $T$ of conditions in $\mathbb{P}$ such that:

1. each level of $T$ is a maximal antichain in $\mathbb{P}$,
2. each node in $T$ has at least two immediate successors,
3. the height of $T$ is $\kappa+1$.

We can achieve item 2 since $\mathbb{P}$ is nontrivial and we use $\leq\kappa$-distributivity for item 3.

Now consider any cofinal branch through $T$ (determined by a node on the top level). Taking all of the nodes that are one step off this branch gives an antichain (in $T$ and also in $\mathbb{P}$) of size $\kappa$.